# Android apk to play store

Tags: android, google-play

Could someone tell me the steps of how to actually get your app (built in AS) on the play store?

I already:

- made myself an Android developers console account.
- paid the 25$ fee.
- built a Signed version of my apk.
  ( i don't know where he built it to, `AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk` ? )

Do i need to rename the built apk to the desired app name ?

So please could someone describe the steps starting from 0, So future people with the same problem can find the solution easly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before publishing your app to play store, you need to follow following two steps:
1. **Get the signed version of apk**: If you are using `Eclipse`,

```
Right click on project >  Android tools > Signed version of application package
```

2. **Zip align the apk obtained from above step**:

```
"\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 "\SignedProject.apk" "\Project_ZipAligned.apk"
```

Comment: or simply export as android application, but OP is anyhow using AS so this does not answer the question.

Comment: It does, the android console was saying something about my signed app needing to be aligned. :)

Answer (score 0):

The project that you created should have a .apk file or you can create a signed apk file . To sign you application go here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html. Once you have you apk file, app icons ready you need to upload them on the website. At this point you will be ready to publish.